# How to add a comment box on wordpress page? in the discussion section of page, allow comments is checked

Tags: comments

Looking for help on a friend's site.

How can I add a comment box to a wordpress page when under discussion both the allow comments box and the allow trackbacks and pingbacks boxes are checked?

When I've checked both those boxes there is no space for a person to leave a comment on the specific page.

Do I need to add any short code or other plug-ins?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to define call to comment box function. `<?php comment_form(); ?>`

Comment: put this into your page template: <?php comments_template(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

You might first want to dig into the generated code to see if there is a 'form' tag somewhere that could be the comment box.

The appearance (and existence) of the comment box on a post is under control of the theme. So I'd also change to one of the 'twenty' themes and see if the box appears. If it does, then you need to contact the theme support page to determine the solution.